# How to use sed (or another Bash command) to replace a word or phrase with text logo and with strings?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sed

I have a script that I want to use to replace a small text with a larger one

This is what I was testing:

I want to make the text:

```
exit 0
```

be replaced by this:

```
for dev in `ls /dev | egrep "^[sh]d[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]+$"`; do umount "/dev/"$dev &>/dev/null ; gio mount -u /media/*/* ; gio mount -u /media/$USER/* ; done
exit 0
```

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Comment: Unrelated: `shopt -s nullglob; disk=(/dev/[sh]d[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]*); declare -p disk`

Comment: As an aside, [don't use `ls` in scripts.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential solution using 'pipe' as a delimiter and escaping some special characters:

```
sed 's|exit 0|ls /dev \|egrep "^[sh]d[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]+$"|'

# Example
echo "some text; exit 0; more text" | sed 's|exit 0|ls /dev \|egrep "^[sh]d[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]+$"|'
some text; ls /dev |egrep "^[sh]d[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]+$"; more text
```

Comment: No, I just want to replace the text "exit 0" with this "ls /dev | egrep "^[sh]d[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]+$"" (without quotes)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @bremaya, glad you solved your problem